# Help Writing Integral Form of Expectation of a Stochastic Proceess

Tags: stochastic-processes, expected-value, radon-nikodym

Let's say I have a stochastic process, $S_t$ which is measurable and adapted to a natural Brownian filtration. Let's assume it is a 1-dimensional process in the reals. I want I write the expected value of a function of this process as follows
$$\mathbb{E}[f(S_T)]$$

I want to write this in the integral form, my question here is the correct way to write this? Are we integrating w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure?

$$\mathbb{E}[f(S_T)] = \int f(S_T) d\mu$$

What is the proper way to write this expected value in integral form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expected value would be written as $$E[f(S_T)] = \int_\Omega f(S_T) d \mathbb{P}$$ where $\mathbb{P}$ is the ambient probability measure. If you know the density of $S_T$, call it $g$, then you can evaluate this as an integral with respect to the Lebesgue measure $$E[f(S_T)] = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) g(x) d x$$

Comment: Deleted mine because we basically say the same things, +1. I would add that the continuous density is typical of continuous Markov processes

Comment: Let's say I had 2 arbitrary processes $S_T$ and $R_T$ but both adapted to a Brownian filtration, then would the integration for both of these processes be over the same probability measure $\mathbb{P}$ or does $\mathbb{P}$ depend on the processes themselves? Ex: $E[f(S_T)]=\int_\Omega f(S_T) d\mathbb{P}$ and $E[f(R_T)]=\int_\Omega f(R_T) d\mathbb{P}$. Or would we have to use some other measure, like $\mathbb{Q}$, for $R_T$?